# Remove zoom from product image on product details page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, product-view

I want to remove zoom functionality from product image on product view page, but I am not sure how to do so. 
It will be a great help if anyone can guide me to achieve this.

I have tried below code in `app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/etc/view.xml`

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">
        <var name="magnifier">
            <var name="enabled">false</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
        </var>
    </vars>
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Change below code in `view.xml` under `<var name="gallery">`:

```
<var name="allowfullscreen">false</var>
```

- clear cache

Comment: Sorry, it is not working for me.

Comment: Have you clear cache? Please make this change in active theme.

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the cache.

Comment: Remove `var` and `pub/static/fronted` folders and deploy content again.

Comment: Tried, but didn't work.